How do "Parallel query processing on partitioned tables and indexes" and "Partitioned table parallelism" differ?
In plain English, "Parallel query processing on partitioned tables and indexes" and "Partitioned table parallelism" sound like the same thing. Yet, in SQL Server 2022, Standard Edition has "Partitioned table parallelism" but not Parallel query processing on partitioned tables and indexes. How do the two features differ?
I have made a reasonable effort to search through the documentation, but have not yet read all of the white papers. I have not been successful in learning what either feature is.

The official documentation was a combination of confusing and wrong for a long time. It's still confusing now, but less wrong than it was. For the most part, the confusion has arisen from different writers authoring and updating different parts of the documentation at different times, using different understanding and emphasis.
The two items you mention refer to the same (set of) features, as far as I am aware.
They were first documented for SQL Server 2008 in Query Processing Enhancements on Partitioned Tables and Indexes, which mentions that Enterprise-equivalent is needed because partitioning was only available in those editions:

Partitioned tables and indexes are supported only in the SQL Server Enterprise, Developer, and Evaluation editions.

That was all a long time before SQL Server 2016 SP1 made programmability features (but not pure performance features) like partitioning widely available across editions.
Erik Darling did some testing in Table Partitioning and Parallelism in SQL Server Standard Edition.
The two feature descriptions refer to the same thing, so there is no difference. The feature is available to Standard Edition users from SQL Server 2016 SP1.
The documentation for "Parallel query processing on partitioned tables and indexes" remains incorrect as far as Standard Edition is concerned.
That page is supremely unhelpful in general because there are no links to determine exactly what a certain feature wording is referring to. We are left to guess at the intentions of the writers and editors.
By the by, the same documentation table also says "Star join query optimizations" is not available on Standard Edition, which is also incorrect. If you're curious about star join query optimizations, you can find details in my article.
